# options on futures

Tags: option-pricing, derivatives, black76

For options on futures in the black model, I do remember that $F$ appearing in the formula must be the forward at maturity of the option (and not the future price).

So, say we have a future maturing quarterly.

And say we have weekly and monthly options on that future.

Then the price of the option will depend on the one week forward, and 1 month forward respectively, and will not depend on the price of the future (which matures in 3 months).

Can you please confirm that is right and suggest a rigorous derivation?

Comment: Do you wish to assume interest rates to be stochastic or constant?

Comment: As I am using Black model with a formula, I asume they are deterministic

Comment: With constant interest rates it is simple (Soumirai's answer). Otherwise see answer by dm63 below if interest rates fluctuations have a big impact on your underlying.

Answer (score 2):

In Black formula, F is the forward of the underlying for the maturity of the option. In the case of an option on a future, the underlying is the future (which has a specific expiry, e.g. an option on the jun21 future).

We can assume that the forward of a future is flat, i.e. equal to spot for any maturity. It is reasonable, because the cost of carry of a future is very small (margin cost but you have netting benefits etc). So you can safely use the current future price as F (in our example, F would be the current value of the jun21 future).

Comment: Not sure about this. Let me give an example : for E-mini there are quarterly futures up to 2 years of maturity, and there are weekly and monthly options. Extrapolating from what you say, if I have a 5 month option, I could price it with any future?? (They have different prices). Also, difference of prices of futures by maturity are not only carry: there may be dividends, or seasnality for commodity futures

Comment: If you are pricing an option that expires in May 2021 and is exercisable into June 2021 futures then $F$ is "the forward price for delivery in may 2021 of a June 2021 future". However, to a good approximation (as explained by Soumirai) that forward price is equal to the price today of the June 2021 future.

Comment: (because a future does not pay dividends and requires no upfront investment (yeah, OK, it does require a margin deposit, but it is small))

Comment: @noob2 exactly, an option on futures references a specific underlying future (say jun21). All your concerns of dividends/seasonality etc, are already priced in the current price of that jun21 future. So if you have an option that references this jun21 future, just use the current price of jun21 future as F in your formula.

Comment: No you should not assume that the futures price is equal to the spot price.

Comment: We are not assuming this. We are pricing an option on the future. There is no "cash spot" involved. Only the future underlying the option.

Answer (score 1):

Using the e mini example , supposing in Dec 2020 you are looking at 5month option on the ESZ1 (ie futures expiring 12mo from now).  Then it is clear that you should be using the ESZ1 futures contract as the underlying, not the 5month futures contract ESK1.  However there is a subtler question of whether today’s price of the ESZ1 is the correct rate to plug into Black model.  What you want is the 5 month forward price on the ESZ1, which is not necessarily exactly equal to the spot price of the ESZ1.

It is well known that certain futures contracts have ‘convexity adjustments’ expressing the difference between forward rates and futures prices , derived from the covariance between the underlying of the futures contract and interest rates between now and expiration of the futures.  This convexity adjustment vanishes at futures expiration by definition.   So, this suggests that at intermediate times the forward rate on a futures contract admits a convexity adjustment that is less than the spot convexity adjustment.  Having said this, I would expect this effect to be negligible for options on the e-mini.  It would be more significant for long dated options on Eurodollar futures where there is a high correlation between interest rates and the value of the futures contracts.

Comment: Technically, if you wanted to use Black formula and there was some convexity adjustment, you would still use the current futures price. That covariance effect would be captured in the implied volatility you're using in your Black formula.

Comment: Agreed that the volatility would capture it, but you have to get the forward correct also

Answer (score 1):

If there is only a spot market or maybe one or two actively traded futures it is acceptable to derive the futures price for that security from it's spot price and a product specific funding cost. You can use a funding spread over a benchmark curve's term structure to price longer futures. In the case of a single stock futures price, you will match the stock futures deliverable date to the option expiration date. If you are pricing an option on an equity futures contract you will price the option to it's expiration and the future to it's normal delivery cycle date (Quarterly etc).